# Codeigniter Ajax - Help Needed with Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hey I'm new to CI and have scoured the internet for a tutorial that will work but for some reason it won't work.  Can someone help me with the code please:

What's the right edit to the code to submit an entry to the database via ajax without reloading the page?

Controller:

```
public function index(){
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->view('template');
```

}

```
function create()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('dbmodel');

    $response = array();
    $this->load->model('dbmodel');
    $result = $this->dbmodel->addnew_row();     
}
```

Model:

```
public function addnew_row() {

    $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
    );
    $result = $this->db->insert('books', $data);
    return $result;
}
```

View Form:

```
<h2>Create</h2> 
<?php echo form_open('welcome/create', array('id'=>'form'));?>


<p>Title: <?php echo form_input('title') ?></p>
<p>Description: <?php echo form_input('description') ?></p> 

<?php echo form_submit('btn_submit','Save'); ?>


<?php echo form_close();?>
```

View AJAX:

```
 // $.POST Example Request
$('#form').submit(function(eve){
    eve.preventDefault();

    var title = $('#title').val();
    var description = $('#description').val();

    url = '<?php echo site_url('welcome/create');?>'
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data:{title:title, description:description
        }

        $(#dynamic_container).html(response.output);
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, at the very least your url variable isn't defined properly nor is it terminated. `var url = '<?php echo site_url('welcome/create');?>';`

Comment: could you post the error message please? You can find it in the developer console (F12->Network->Trigger ajax request, and  then select the ajax request in the list)

Answer (score 1):

Ok,At first you need to briefly go through the syntax of [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) before using it.

Now going though the AJAX code you mentioned in the question , this block of code is not suppose to be there

```
$(#dynamic_container).html(response.output);
```

AJAX provides `Callback Function Queues` to manipulate response before/after an AJAX call has been successfully completed , and in your case using `success` will resolve the issue :

```
  $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data:{title:title, description:description
        },
        success : function(response){
        $(#dynamic_container).html(response.output);
        }
    });
```

And you might be interested in using [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).